# Print on terminal and into file simultaneously?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I have a shell script that greps some data.. I want to print the result into a file, but doing that prevents the result being displayed on the terminal. Is there a way that can both print the result on the screen and also write into a file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pipe your output to the [`tee`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) command.

Example:

```
[me@home]$ echo hello | tee out.txt
hello
[me@home]$ cat out.txt 
hello
```

Note that the stdout of `echo` is printed out as well as written to the file specified by thr `tee` command.

Answer (score 6):

Note you can add the `-a` flag to `tee` to append to the output file

```
[me@home]$ echo hello | tee out.txt
hello
[me@home]$ echo hello again | tee -a out.txt
hello again
[me@home]$ cat out.txt
hello
hello again
```

Answer (score 1):

Does exactly your thing

http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method without tee.

```
echo "some content" > /dev/tty > log_file.txt
```