# Printing System.out.println statements on console while executing the jar and redirecting its output to file

Tags: java

I have a small java program which asks the user to input two dates. I want to package this whole program into a jar file. when I try to execute the jar file via command line and redirecting the output to a log file( like this: `java -jar Sample.jar >> Sample.log`), all the `System.out.println` statements and log statements are printed to the external file, not on console. I want to see the `System.out.println` statements printed on the console and log4j log statements in the external file even if the user redirects the output to log file.  Please note that I have set the log4j appender to 'Console'. Any idea on how to do that?

**The sample program is below:**

```
public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] arg) {
        logger.debug("start of the main method");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter start date in the format YYYY-MM-DD");
        String startDate = in.nextLine();
        logger.debug("The entered start date is " + startDate);
        System.out.println("Please enter end date in the format YYYY-MM-DD");
        logger.debug("The entered end date is " + endDate);

    }
}
```

Comment: _even if the user redirects the output to log file_ What difference does it make to you if the user decides to redirect the console output when she runs your program?

Comment: @Abra Yep, it makes sense to me as the user should be asked to enter the dates on the console it self. The dates any way should be entered on the console, not in the file.

Comment: I believe there is a difference between redirecting standard **output** and redirecting standard **input**. When I write a java application that requires user input, I usually provide a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `>>` you can use the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25425207/4880379). So instead of:

`java -jar Sample.jar >> Sample.log`

... you could do:

`java -jar Sample.jar | tee -a Sample.log`

For Windows you can try to use something from:
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file)
or [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/278115/windows-command-line-redirection-to-text-file-while-also-seeing-output)

`tee` can be accessed using using Windows PowerShell. This can be opened from start menu.

[This question really helped me in finding a way to access `tee` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command)

Comment: `tee` is not available by default. I've linked some other answers related to the Windows

Comment: Your answer helped me a bit to research further on this. I will edit your answer with my findings. Plus one for the answer. Thanks

Comment: tee can be accessed using using Windows PowerShell. This can be opened from start menu.